# Different results when searching for website with "site:"?

Tags: google

I'm looking at the website www.example.com and when it's Googled by itself, it returns the normal results that are expected for it.

When you Google "site:www.example.com" it comes up with information that shouldn't be related to this website though.

I cannot seem to find any information as to why this might be happening. Help please.

EDIT: An important update that I noticed recently is that "site:www.example.com" is actually referring to the domain with https://. It doesn't have an SSL and there are no references to https:// in the file or database. Not sure why Google would display it that way, especially for searches with "site:" only.

Comment: Can you explain *it comes up with information that shouldn't be related to this website* more? Using a site: search should only show results from your site. Can you give us some clue - otherwise, we cannot even guess what your problem is.

Comment: I had used the exact domain which could have been useful for further information, however it turned out to be against the rules. Sorry about that.

Comment: I noticed though, that the entry when the website is looked up with "site:example.com" is returned with https://example.com even though the website doesn't have an SSL. For some reason "site:" calls out https:// the domain, and is probably why it displays wrong information on Google.

Comment: I played with your domain name in search a bit. I got it from your original question. ***The result is weird*** and I cannot explain it. Otherwise, apart from the one entry, it all looks normal. Can you update the original question with this new information?? Maybe someone will have an idea. Google does make mistakes from time to time that are corrected over time. This looks like one of those mistakes. I wish I had an answer for you. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for checking on it though, I'll upvote you as soon as I have enough reputation to do so, since I just recently found out about this StackExchange.

Comment: We have some real experts here. In particular, the Pro Webmasters is a great group of people! Hopefully, someone would have an idea and can give a decent answer. It does look like one of those mistakes that Google makes from time to time. These often correct themselves, but still may take a while. You can give Google a heads-up by posting a question on Googles product forums. Google engineers troll this site and the Google product forums for issues. Trust me - Google does take action even if they do not respond.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much to go on here so these are somewhat random ideas:

Have you verified every meaningful sub-domain and protocol (and set the preferred version)?

http://example.com

https://example.com

http://www.example.com

https://www.example.com

It might also be smart to look into what various search engines have in their page cache (maybe archive.org, also).

If there's any A/B testing scripts, tag management solutions, etc. It's probably smart to double check all those, too.